# how to combine error with printf in haskell

Tags: haskell, printf, variadic-functions, composition, abort

I found the Haskell module `Text.Printf`.
It provides a sort of C-like printf. For example `printf "hi %d\n" 42` will produce the string `"hi 42\n"`.

That is pretty neat. Now something like `error $ printf "hi %d\n" 42` aborts the program with the error message. That is also neat.

But I would like to make a more general function `abort` such that `abort "hi %d\n" 42` has the same effect. In other words I want to combine error with printf. But it is completely unclear to me how to do that, because of printf accepting a variable number of arguments.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I fear you'll have to replicate most of the type-level machinery that makes `printf` work, using a bunch of typeclasses to simulate "variadic" functions.

Comment: I think the main problem will be that `error` has type `a`, so also `a -> b`, so `printf`s tricks with typeclasses will be more problematic.

Comment: That being said, `error` is usually *not* a good idea. Usually one works with `fail`, or some other item that returns, depending on the monadic context a value.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Why have you un-closed this as a duplicate? [How to create a polyvariadic function which itself uses another polyvariadic function (e.g. printf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76184935/625403) appears to ask exactly the same question, and has a good, thorough answer. If you disagree I would love to know why.

Comment: @amalloy: because there are additional challenges: one is how for example `add :: Int -> Int -> Int` with `add 0 = abort "some error"` would know "when" to error, after the first parameter, the second, what if the error happens when formatting, and the trick with the typeclasses will thus likely not work since `error` can be any type so also a `a -> b` (which is an instance of `Printf`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The linked question seems to have both of those challenges as well. Its accepted answer says that there is no good way to get type `a` from your function, rather than type `Void`. If you have a solution that solves either one of these problems, I'm sure it would be very welcome on that linked question, and the duplicate indicator would do a great job of helping viewers of this question find the answer.